# Word wrap in Footer template in Itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I'm facing issue in footer while generating the PDF through itextsharp.

I've tried by creating template and also directly through content byte.
While generating through content byte, it is overriding the other footer template which is showing the page number of the pdf.

If I try using the template, it is partially showing the text. It is not able to wrap the word as it does when we use pdfpcell.

I've attached images respective to both the issues.

```
public class ITextEvents : PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        PdfContentByte cb;
        PdfTemplate headerTemplate, footerTemplate, footerTemplate1,footerTemplate2;
        BaseFont bf = null;
        BaseFont bfb = null;
        int pageCount = 0;
        public bool IsLastPage = false;

    public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        bfb = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

        cb = writer.DirectContent;
        headerTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(50, 50);
        footerTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(50, 50);
        footerTemplate1 = cb.CreateTemplate(50, 50);
        footerTemplate2= cb.CreateTemplate(480, 100);
    }

    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
        Font baseFontNormal = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Font baseFontBig = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        String text = "Page " + writer.PageNumber + " of ";

        //Add paging to header  
        if (writer.PageNumber > 1)
        {
            {
                cb.BeginText();
                cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                cb.SetTextMatrix(document.PageSize.GetLeft(25), document.PageSize.GetTop(25));
                cb.ShowText("Continued...");
                cb.EndText();
            }
        }
        //Add paging to footer  
        {

            //footer using template
            footerTemplate2.BeginText();
            footerTemplate2.SetFontAndSize(bf, 10);
            footerTemplate2.SetTextMatrix(0, 2);
            footerTemplate2.ShowText("This order is placed subject to xyz institiute, 44, xyz street, xyz town, xyz state, xyz country" + " purchase terms and conditions.");
            footerTemplate2.EndText();

            cb.AddTemplate(footerTemplate2, document.PageSize.GetLeft(25), document.PageSize.GetBottom(30));

            // footer using contentbyte

            //cb.BeginText();
            //cb.SetFontAndSize(bfb, 10);
            //cb.SetTextMatrix(document.PageSize.GetLeft(25), document.PageSize.GetBottom(25));
            //cb.ShowText("This order is placed subject to xyz institute, 44, xyz street, xyz town, xyz state, xyz country" + " purchase terms and conditions.");
            //cb.EndText();


            cb.BeginText();
            cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 10);
            cb.SetTextMatrix(document.PageSize.GetRight(75), document.PageSize.GetBottom(25));
            cb.ShowText(text);
            cb.EndText();
            float len = bf.GetWidthPoint(text, 10);

            if (!IsLastPage)
                cb.AddTemplate(footerTemplate1, document.PageSize.GetRight(74), document.PageSize.GetBottom(45));

            cb.AddTemplate(footerTemplate, document.PageSize.GetRight(74) + len, document.PageSize.GetBottom(25));
        }
        pageCount += 1;
    }

    public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);

        footerTemplate1.BeginText();
        footerTemplate1.SetFontAndSize(bf, 10);
        footerTemplate1.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
        footerTemplate1.ShowText("Continued...");
        footerTemplate1.EndText();

        footerTemplate.BeginText();
        footerTemplate.SetFontAndSize(bf, 10);
        footerTemplate.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
        footerTemplate.ShowText((writer.PageNumber - 1).ToString());
        footerTemplate.EndText();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that **iTextSharp** was renamed to **iText for .NET** more than two years ago. Looking at your code, I see that you are not using the latest version of iText, which is [iText 7](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET). Please note that previous versions of iText are no longer supported. Maintenance releases such as 5.5.13 are created for customers with a support contract, but new development on iText 5 has stopped. Please upgrade to iText 7.

Comment: If you can't upgrade to iText 7 because you're working on an existing project, please be aware of the fact that iText can't be distributed in the context of a closed source application without having purchased a commercial license. If you're working on such an application, please make sure you have a support contract and post your question on the closed ticketing system of iText Software (the answer to your question is rather trivial). Using Stack Overflow for commercial support is not allowed by the https://stackexchange.com Terms and Conditions.

Comment: You are using low-level methods (in particular `ShowText`) which immediately translate into PDF instructions that have no word wrap feature. You should use a higher level API, e.g. a `ColumnText` instance

Comment: Thank you mkl. ColumnText worked for me.